# Java Output Error String Manupulation

Tags: java

I have this code to calculate the no of times consecutive characters that are similar in a string.

```
public class Solution {

public static  int count;

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = s.nextInt();//no of testcases
    char a1,b1;
    for(int i=0;i<=a;i++)
    {
        String str=s.nextLine();
        int len=str.length();
        for(int b=0;b<len-1;b++)
        { 
            a1=str.charAt(b);           
            b1=str.charAt(b+1);
            if(a1==b1) count++;               
        }
        System.out.println(count);
        count=0;
    }
}
}
```

Input:

```
1
AAAA
```

Expected output:

```
3
```

Program output:

```
0
3
```

I cannot find out the error.

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an incorrect for loop condition. Change "i <= a" to "i < a".

Comment: When I change My loop then for the input                                  5
AAAA
BBBBB
ABABABAB
BABABA
AAABBB                                                             output is                                                              0
3
4
0
0
and the last 4 is missing and 0 in the beginning is still there.

Comment: You also need to add a nextLine() call after your first call to nextInt().

Comment: thnx but why did i have to add nexLine after nextInt ,I only needed an interger input.

Comment: nextInt() reads the number of testcases but does not read the line break character that follows it. The first nextLine() call in the loop will read this line break character and interpret it as an empty testcase.